# General suggestions to find a SegFault within an MPI Python program

Tags: python, c, debugging, segmentation-fault, mpi

I write MPI programs with Python using the mpi4py library. The Python generates and calls low-level C code.

I just got a seg-fault and need to track it down.

If I were writing in straight C I would compile and run my program in `gdb`, find the offending line of code, and start debugging from there.

If I were writing in Python I would still use `gdb` (you can call `gdb python filename.py` and gdb will point you to the offending line of C.)

But alas I'm using MPI which is using Python which is using C. I get a stack trace like this

```
mrocklin@baconost:~/workspace/ape$ mpiexec -np 3 -hostfile tmp/hostfile -rankfile tmp/rankfile python ape/codegen/run.py tmp/
[baconost:27370] *** Process received signal ***
[baconost:27370] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[baconost:27370] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[baconost:27370] Failing at address: 0x8
[baconost:27370] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfc60) [0x7fcd529c5c60]
[baconost:27370] [ 1] /home/mrocklin/Software/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.0(MPI_Comm_get_errhandler+0xa0) [0x7fcd46fae240]
[baconost:27370] [ 2] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so(+0x2ddbc) [0x7fcd47234dbc]
[baconost:27370] [ 3] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so(initMPI+0x1f2e) [0x7fcd4724f95e]
[baconost:27370] [ 4] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(_PyImport_LoadDynamicModule+0xc2) [0x7fcd52cc2e02]
[baconost:27370] [ 5] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xecd90) [0x7fcd52cc0d90]
[baconost:27370] [ 6] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed031) [0x7fcd52cc1031]
[baconost:27370] [ 7] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x2be) [0x7fcd52cc206e]
[baconost:27370] [ 8] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xd3fed) [0x7fcd52ca7fed]
[baconost:27370] [ 9] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x7fcd52c19d18]
[baconost:27370] [10] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x56) [0x7fcd52ca8516]
[baconost:27370] [11] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x28b8) [0x7fcd52caba78]
[baconost:27370] [12] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8d2) [0x7fcd52cb0722]
[baconost:27370] [13] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32) [0x7fcd52cb0772]
[baconost:27370] [14] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2) [0x7fcd52cbf6e2]
[baconost:27370] [15] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xebcae) [0x7fcd52cbfcae]
[baconost:27370] [16] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xecd90) [0x7fcd52cc0d90]
[baconost:27370] [17] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed264) [0x7fcd52cc1264]
[baconost:27370] [18] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x118) [0x7fcd52cc1ec8]
[baconost:27370] [19] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xd3fed) [0x7fcd52ca7fed]
[baconost:27370] [20] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x7fcd52c19d18]
[baconost:27370] [21] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x56) [0x7fcd52ca8516]
[baconost:27370] [22] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x28b8) [0x7fcd52caba78]
[baconost:27370] [23] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8d2) [0x7fcd52cb0722]
[baconost:27370] [24] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32) [0x7fcd52cb0772]
[baconost:27370] [25] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2) [0x7fcd52cbf6e2]
[baconost:27370] [26] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xebcae) [0x7fcd52cbfcae]
[baconost:27370] [27] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed58d) [0x7fcd52cc158d]
[baconost:27370] [28] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xecd90) [0x7fcd52cc0d90]
[baconost:27370] [29] /home/mrocklin/Software/epd-7.2-1-rh5-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed264) [0x7fcd52cc1264]
[baconost:27370] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 0 with PID 27370 on node baconost.cs.uchicago.edu exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Two questions:

1. In the general case what is the best way to debug programs with this software stack after a bug has been detected (I'd like to avoid the "you should prevent bugs with testing instead of diagnosing them" comments. I agree with this but sometimes segfaults happen despite our best efforts)
2. In this specific case is this pointing me to an MPI/`mpi4py` issue? The last few lines suggest that maybe this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem to this specific error was that older versions of OpenMPI don't handle rankfiles very well. This bug was reported and appears to be fixed as of `1.6.2`. Apparently this part of the code is rarely used and untested.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you are using disparent modules/products there is potential for a version mis-match.  Check you are using the right version combinations of Python/MPI/mpi4y.

Having checked all that, just about all you can do is:

1. Assume that it is your code that is causing the problem - generally a good starting point.
2. Try to isolate the case down to a few simple statements which cause the SEGV.  I know, that's the hard part.
3. If the bug in your code is not obvious, then ask the specific question about your code.
4. If all else fails, then maybe it is a bug elsewhere.

Comment: I've verified that the versions of Python/MPI/mpi4py on all systems are identical.